# Load and Unload assembly AppDomain.Load(bytes)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I want to do something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = item.CompiledRule;
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestDomain");
Assembly a = domain.Load(bytes);
//Something do with Assembly 
AppDomain.Unload(domain);
```

I have only assembly bytes. When I dont use AppDomain It works perfect, but when i do it like this it crushed:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
```

Comment: Which line fails, and is there any more information in an inner exception?

Comment: Cant reproduce the problem, works fine for me

Comment: Inner Exception is null. Its not work at line 3. Where I do something like this `Assembly.Load(bytes)` It works perfect

Answer (score 0):

When you load assembly from a byte array, it's dependencies are not resolved automatically. One possible way to solve the problem is to subscribe to AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event to load your dependencies. Note that the resolution code must run inside that AppDomain.

Comment: How to load dependencies?? Can you take me example? Thanks